# Android: push notifications crash application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented push notification in my application. They works well when the application is opened or it is in the background but when the the application is closed a pup up message on my screen is displayed saying that a problem occurred in the application.

here there is the piece of code that implements push notifications.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
FeedReaderDbHelperMessages mDbHelper;
/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "GCM Intent";
/**
 * Db access object
 * */

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras);
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification(extras);
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN").putExtras(extras);
            this.sendBroadcast(i);
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());

        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(Bundle msg) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Profile userProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    String user_id = userProfile.getId();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, drawnerActivity.class);
    newIntent.setAction("OPEN_NOTIFICATION");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,newIntent, 0);

    mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelperMessages(getApplicationContext());
    UpdateMessages updateMessages = new UpdateMessages(mDbHelper);

    if(msg.getString("notificationType").equals("question"))
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notifica_domanda_mini)
                        .setContentTitle("MyApp")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("New question"))
                        .setContentText("New question");

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(400);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        updateMessages.update(user_id);
    }
    if(msg.getString("notificationType").equals("answer"))
    {
        Contact userAnswer = ContactListFragment.findContactById(msg.getString("friendId"));
        Timestamp notificationTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(msg.getString("timestamp"));
        Log.i(TAG, "Answer notification received from: "+ userAnswer.getName() + " timestamp: " + notificationTimestamp.toString());
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_mini_dialog)
                        .setContentTitle("MyApp")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("New answer"))
                        .setContentText(userAnswer.getName() + " answered");

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        long[] pattern = {
                0,  // Start immediately
                100,
                100,
                100
        };

        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);

        //updateMessages.updateRowWithAnswer(msg.getString("questionId"), msg.getString("answer"));
        FeedReaderDbHelperNotification mDbHelperNotifications = new FeedReaderDbHelperNotification(getApplicationContext());
        UpdateNotifications updateNotifications = new UpdateNotifications(mDbHelperNotifications, mDbHelper);
        updateNotifications.update(user_id);
        //NotificationFragment.addNotification(new NotificationImpl(notificationTimestamp, 1, 0, msg.getString("questionId"), ""), getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

the problem is a `NullPointerException` here `String user_id = userProfile.getId();`. The userProfile cames from `com.facebook.Profile` class because I use `facebook sdk` to keep session. Why is it null?

here there is the stacktrace

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bellantoni.chetta.lieme.GcmIntentService.sendNotification(GcmIntentService.java:80)
        at com.bellantoni.chetta.lieme.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:63)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code block is the first time you are calling `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` then the problem is likely that the user has not logged in yet, so there is no user profile, hence the `NullPointerException`. I had a similar problem a while back and this was the issue.

Make sure that you are calling the Login callback from the FacebookSDK. Hope this helps.